Why is Keycloak resulting in "Cookie not found" error after IDP initiated login?
I am setting up IDP initiated authentication from ServiceA to my application using Keycloak. So far, I provided all necessary configurations required by ServiceA and I've also configured SAML Identity Provider on the Keycloak and configured it with the appropriate configuration values received from ServiceA.
The Issue:
When I click on the application icon on the ServiceA portal, the flow initiates as expected. I receive SAML response with status Success, Destination attribute URL value matches Assertion Consumer service endpoint value configured on ServiceA, Audience is OK as well, but after being redirected to the Keycloak, I encounter an error saying:
We are sorry... Cookie not found. Please make sure cookies are enabled in your browser.
Here is the message from the Keycloak logs:
type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=myrealm, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=XX.XXX.XXX.XXX, error=cookie_not_found
And this is what Devtools in Firefox says:
Cookie “KC_STATE_CHECKER” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None” attribute to it.   
Keycloak version: 22.0.1
In this version there is no option to do any configuration related to the cookies (at least from UI and REST API point of view).
Questions:

Why does Keycloak struggles to find KC_STATE_CHECKER cookie in this flow?
Can I somehow ensure that SameSite=None attribute is properly added to Keycloak cookies?
Are there some additional configurations that need to be done on Keycloak or on ServiceA?

Thank you for your answers.
I re-checked all the URL's (both on ServiceA and in my Keycloak configuration). I even contacted ServiceA support to provide me with SAML metadata descriptor so I don't have to copy the URL's and other parameters.
I also enabled DEBUG and TRACE logs in the Keycloak but I haven't found anything useful there.
I tried different browsers, incognito modes, clearing cookies and all that stuff.
I also tried removing https:// and path in the Audience section as I read somewhere it might cause issues but it also didn't help.
Also, guys from the support confirmed that my configuration is OK but of course they can't help me with if the problem is on my side (Keycloak). They even checked SAML response that I receive after clicking application icon on ServiceA portal - and they confirmed that response is correct and valid.
Of course, apart from all of this, I don't even have to mention days spent googling, reading similar issues on Keycloak github page, and even reading Keycloak source code.

are you using HTTP:// or HTTPS:// in the browser? I wrote a blog post here https://nestenius.se/net/debugging-cookie-problems/  about how to debug cookies issues in your browser.

I am using HTTPS://.  Thank you for sharing your blog post, I find it quite good and useful! However, my problem still remains.

Solved!
Things I had to do:

Create SAML client
Add IDP-Initiated SSO URL name
Set Assertion Consumer Service Post Binding URL

Breakthrough:
When creating the client, Client ID must match the Issuer value sent in AuthNRequest because Keycloak pulls the issuer from the Authn SAML request and match it to a client by this value.
Next thing that needs to be done is to set IDP-Initiated SSO URL name. Leaving this blank will disable IDP initiated flow. The target URL that you need to reference from your browser will be in the following format:

server-root/realms/{realm}/protocol/saml/clients/{client-url-name}

The target Identity Provider (IdP)-initiated SSO URL is the Assertion Consumer Service (ACS) endpoint of your application. This is the endpoint where service you're integrating with, acting as the IdP, sends the SAML assertion after authenticating the user. This URL must be registered with service you're integrating with as part of the SAML integration, ensuring that SAML assertions are securely and correctly routed to your application.
Next, under Advanced tab, we need to set Assertion Consumer Service POST Binding URL. This should be the URL to your backend application that just do the redirect to your frontend application. Particularly in my case, I configured this endpoint on Ingress in way it does Permanent Redirect (301) to my frontend application (whenever it match https://myapp.com/saml-continue URL). However, it is also possible just to open simple endpoint in your backend server which will do the redirect to frontend.

See the KeyCloak release notes and here it says:

Removal of legacy cookies
Keycloak no longer sends _LEGACY cookies, which where introduced as a
work-around to older browsers not supporting the SameSite flag on
cookies.
The _LEGACY cookies also served another purpose, which was to allow
login from an insecure context. Although, this is not recommended at
all in production deployments of Keycloak, it is fairly frequent to
access Keycloak over http outside of localhost. As an alternative to
the _LEGACY cookies Keycloak now doesn’t set the secure flag and sets
SameSite=Lax instead of SameSite=None when it detects an insecure
context is used.

It also says for versin 25.0.0:

Cookies updates SameSite attribute set for all cookies
The following cookies did not use to set the SameSite attribute, which
in recent browser versions results in them defaulting to SameSite=Lax:
KC_STATE_CHECKER now sets SameSite=Strict

KC_RESTART now sets SameSite=None

KEYCLOAK_LOCALE now sets SameSite=None

KEYCLOAK_REMEMBER_ME now sets SameSite=None

The default value SameSite=Lax causes issues with POST based bindings,
mostly applicable to SAML, but also used in some OpenID Connect /
OAuth 2.0 flows.


any workaround how to solve the issue. I'm also getting the error when configuring IAM identity center as external provider for keycloak

Hi Swarnim. Check my latest comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/79260513/9858901.
